# Setting cookie from lambda to S3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an Node application on Lambda and static React app on S3. The idea is simple:
I have a dynamoDB with users data and REST endpoints to add/delete/update users. When user authenticates it will be able to use all the endpoints above.

I've set up Cognito because I wanted `Sign in with Google` option and decided to set it up.

React application has 2 routes, `/` and `/Users`. On `/` I have a Sign in with Google button. When user signs in, it is redirected to Lambda `URL` with code query `...code=<>`. I parse query and retrieve token from it using `/oauth2/token` endpoint and then set it to cookie.

So cookie is only set on server side, how do I set cookie on S3 side? Since S3 and Lambda are on different domains how do I communicate with S3? But I've read that `Amazon S3 and some HTTP servers don’t process cookies.` So I'm little lost, Is it impossible to set cookies on S3? Is there any other service which is used for static websites with cookie capabilities?

**P.S.**

My point is that I'm missing some knowledge of AWS services, I thought S3 could be used as static website (in my case a clinet) to communicate with Node application. If I should be using some other service for this purpose please suggest

Comment: `it is redirected to Lambda URL` - what do you mean?

Comment: In Cognito you specify the URL where you want users to redirect when user is logged in. I specified Node endpoint to parse the code and retrieve token from it

Comment: Okay that's much better :) Take 5 minutes to *please* take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question to help us help you

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `how do I set cookie on S3 side`? S3 is a file storage solution, it's not a frontend application

Comment: `Is it impossible to set cookies on S3?` - https://xyproblem.info/ - what is your **actual question**?

Comment: How do I know from Node application if user is signed in? I need to send it from the client right? In my case client is S3 application which need to have a cookie to send

Comment: Your client is an application which *communicates* with S3 - just store the user's access credentials? Read the cookie then send it in your request - S3 doesn't work with cookies

Comment: Which AWS service should I use as an web app client to communicate with Lambda?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238129/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-ojs).